# Why do I keep getting this error when I try to deploy my Kotlin/Spring-Boot - Application on Heroku?

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, maven, heroku

When I try to deploy my code in Heroku, I get the following stack trace:

```
[WARNING] Error injecting: org.springframework.boot.maven.RepackageMojo
       java.lang.TypeNotPresentException: Type org.springframework.boot.maven.RepackageMojo not present
           at org.eclipse.sisu.space.URLClassSpace.loadClass (URLClassSpace.java:147)
           at org.eclipse.sisu.space.NamedClass.load (NamedClass.java:46)
           at org.eclipse.sisu.space.AbstractDeferredClass.get (AbstractDeferredClass.java:48)
           at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.provision (ProviderInternalFactory.java:85)
           at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.provision (InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:57)
           at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory$1.call (ProviderInternalFactory.java:66)
           at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision (ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:112)
           at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision (ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:127)
           at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback.provision (ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:66)
           at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.circularGet (ProviderInternalFactory.java:61)
           at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.get (InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:47)
           at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$1.get (InjectorImpl.java:1050)
           at org.eclipse.sisu.inject.Guice4$1.get (Guice4.java:162)
           at org.eclipse.sisu.inject.LazyBeanEntry.getValue (LazyBeanEntry.java:81)
           at org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.LazyPlexusBean.getValue (LazyPlexusBean.java:51)
           at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup (DefaultPlexusContainer.java:263)
           at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup (DefaultPlexusContainer.java:255)
           at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.getConfiguredMojo (DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:520)
           at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:124)
           at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute2 (MojoExecutor.java:370)
           at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute (MojoExecutor.java:351)
           at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:215)
           at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:171)
           at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:163)
           at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
           at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
           at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
           at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
           at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:298)
           at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
           at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
           at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:960)
           at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:293)
           at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:196)
           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
           at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
           at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
           at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
           at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
           at org.apache.maven.wrapper.BootstrapMainStarter.start (BootstrapMainStarter.java:53)
           at org.apache.maven.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute (WrapperExecutor.java:152)
           at org.apache.maven.wrapper.MavenWrapperMain.main (MavenWrapperMain.java:76)
       Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/springframework/boot/maven/RepackageMojo has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 61.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0
           at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1 (Native Method)
           at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass (ClassLoader.java:757)
           at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass (SecureClassLoader.java:142)
           at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass (URLClassLoader.java:473)
           at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100 (URLClassLoader.java:74)
           at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run (URLClassLoader.java:369)
           at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run (URLClassLoader.java:363)
           at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged (Native Method)
           at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass (URLClassLoader.java:362)
           at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClassFromSelf (ClassRealm.java:425)
           at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy.loadClass (SelfFirstStrategy.java:42)
           at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.unsynchronizedLoadClass (ClassRealm.java:271)
           at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass (ClassRealm.java:247)
           at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass (ClassRealm.java:239)
           at org.eclipse.sisu.space.URLClassSpace.loadClass (URLClassSpace.java:139)
           at org.eclipse.sisu.space.NamedClass.load (NamedClass.java:46)
           at org.eclipse.sisu.space.AbstractDeferredClass.get (AbstractDeferredClass.java:48)
           at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.provision (ProviderInternalFactory.java:85)
           at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.provision (InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:57)
           at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory$1.call (ProviderInternalFactory.java:66)
           at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision (ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:112)
           at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision (ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:127)
           at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback.provision (ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:66)
           at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.circularGet (ProviderInternalFactory.java:61)
           at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.get (InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:47)
           at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$1.get (InjectorImpl.java:1050)
           at org.eclipse.sisu.inject.Guice4$1.get (Guice4.java:162)
           at org.eclipse.sisu.inject.LazyBeanEntry.getValue (LazyBeanEntry.java:81)
           at org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.LazyPlexusBean.getValue (LazyPlexusBean.java:51)
           at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup (DefaultPlexusContainer.java:263)
           at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup (DefaultPlexusContainer.java:255)
           at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.getConfiguredMojo (DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:520)
           at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:124)
           at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute2 (MojoExecutor.java:370)
           at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute (MojoExecutor.java:351)
           at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:215)
           at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:171)
           at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:163)
           at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
           at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
           at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
           at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
           at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:298)
           at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
           at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
           at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:960)
           at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:293)
           at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:196)
           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
           at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
           at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
           at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
           at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
           at org.apache.maven.wrapper.BootstrapMainStarter.start (BootstrapMainStarter.java:53)
           at org.apache.maven.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute (WrapperExecutor.java:152)
           at org.apache.maven.wrapper.MavenWrapperMain.main (MavenWrapperMain.java:76)
       [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
       [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
       [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
       [INFO] Total time:  23.974 s
       [INFO] Finished at: 2023-06-05T14:16:21Z
       [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
       [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:3.0.5:repackage (repackage) on project quickaid-backend: Execution repackage of goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:3.0.5:repackage failed: Unable to load the mojo 'repackage' in the plugin 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:3.0.5' due to an API incompatibility: org.codehaus.plexus.component.repository.exception.ComponentLookupException: org/springframework/boot/maven/RepackageMojo has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 61.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0
       [ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------
       [ERROR] realm =    plugin>org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:3.0.5
       [ERROR] strategy = org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy
       [ERROR] urls[0] = file:/tmp/codon/tmp/cache/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-maven-plugin/3.0.5/spring-boot-maven-plugin-3.0.5.jar
       [ERROR] urls[1] = file:/tmp/codon/tmp/cache/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-context/6.0.7/spring-context-6.0.7.jar
       [ERROR] urls[2] = file:/tmp/codon/tmp/cache/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-aop/6.0.7/spring-aop-6.0.7.jar
       [ERROR] urls[3] = file:/tmp/codon/tmp/cache/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-beans/6.0.7/spring-beans-6.0.7.jar
       [ERROR] urls[4] = file:/tmp/codon/tmp/cache/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-core/6.0.7/spring-core-6.0.7.jar
       [ERROR] urls[5] = file:/tmp/codon/tmp/cache/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-jcl/6.0.7/spring-jcl-6.0.7.jar
       [ERROR] urls[6] = file:/tmp/codon/tmp/cache/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-expression/6.0.7/spring-expression-6.0.7.jar
       [ERROR] urls[7] = file:/tmp/codon/tmp/cache/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-buildpack-platform/3.0.5/spring-boot-buildpack-platform-3.0.5.jar
       [ERROR] urls[8] = file:/tmp/codon/tmp/cache/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-databind/2.14.2/jackson-databind-2.14.2.jar
       [ERROR] urls[9] = file:/tmp/codon/tmp/cache/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-annotations/2.14.2/jackson-annotations-2.14.2.jar
       [ERROR] urls[10] = file:/tmp/codon/tmp/cache/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-core/2.14.2/jackson-core-2.14.2.jar
       [ERROR] urls[11] = file:/tmp/codon/tmp/cache/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/module/jackson-module-parameter-names/2.14.2/jackson-module-parameter-names-2.14.2.jar
       [ERROR] urls[12] = file:/tmp/codon/tmp/cache/.m2/repository/net/java/dev/jna/jna-platform/5.7.0/jna-platform-5.7.0.jar
       [ERROR] urls[13] = file:/tmp/codon/tmp/cache/.m2/repository/net/java/dev/jna/jna/5.7.0/jna-5.7.0.jar
       [ERROR] urls[14] = file:/tmp/codon/tmp/cache/.m2/repository/org/apache/commons/commons-compress/1.21/commons-compress-1.21.jar
       [ERROR] urls[15] = file:/tmp/codon/tmp/cache/.m2/repository/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpclient/4.5.14/httpclient-4.5.14.jar
       [ERROR] urls[16] = file:/tmp/codon/tmp/cache/.m2/repository/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpcore/4.4.16/httpcore-4.4.16.jar
       [ERROR] urls[17] = file:/tmp/codon/tmp/cache/.m2/repository/commons-codec/commons-codec/1.11/commons-codec-1.11.jar
       [ERROR] urls[18] = file:/tmp/codon/tmp/cache/.m2/repository/org/tomlj/tomlj/1.0.0/tomlj-1.0.0.jar
       [ERROR] urls[19] = file:/tmp/codon/tmp/cache/.m2/repository/org/antlr/antlr4-runtime/4.7.2/antlr4-runtime-4.7.2.jar
       [ERROR] urls[20] = file:/tmp/codon/tmp/cache/.m2/repository/com/google/code/findbugs/jsr305/3.0.2/jsr305-3.0.2.jar
       [ERROR] urls[21] = file:/tmp/codon/tmp/cache/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-loader-tools/3.0.5/spring-boot-loader-tools-3.0.5.jar
       [ERROR] urls[22] = file:/tmp/codon/tmp/cache/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/plexus/plexus-build-api/0.0.7/plexus-build-api-0.0.7.jar
       [ERROR] urls[23] = file:/tmp/codon/tmp/cache/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/1.5.8/plexus-utils-1.5.8.jar
       [ERROR] urls[24] = file:/tmp/codon/tmp/cache/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/3.2.4/maven-shade-plugin-3.2.4.jar
       [ERROR] urls[25] = file:/tmp/codon/tmp/cache/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/sisu/sisu-inject-bean/1.4.2/sisu-inject-bean-1.4.2.jar
       [ERROR] urls[26] = file:/tmp/codon/tmp/cache/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/sisu/sisu-guice/2.1.7/sisu-guice-2.1.7-noaop.jar
       [ERROR] urls[27] = file:/tmp/codon/tmp/cache/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/aether/aether-util/1.7/aether-util-1.7.jar
       [ERROR] urls[28] = file:/tmp/codon/tmp/cache/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-interpolation/1.14/plexus-interpolation-1.14.jar
       [ERROR] urls[29] = file:/tmp/codon/tmp/cache/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-component-annotations/1.5.5/plexus-component-annotations-1.5.5.jar
       [ERROR] urls[30] = file:/tmp/codon/tmp/cache/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/plexus/plexus-sec-dispatcher/1.3/plexus-sec-dispatcher-1.3.jar
       [ERROR] urls[31] = file:/tmp/codon/tmp/cache/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/plexus/plexus-cipher/1.4/plexus-cipher-1.4.jar
       [ERROR] urls[32] = file:/tmp/codon/tmp/cache/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/shared/maven-artifact-transfer/0.12.0/maven-artifact-transfer-0.12.0.jar
       [ERROR] urls[33] = file:/tmp/codon/tmp/cache/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/shared/maven-common-artifact-filters/3.0.1/maven-common-artifact-filters-3.0.1.jar
       [ERROR] urls[34] = file:/tmp/codon/tmp/cache/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/shared/maven-shared-utils/3.1.0/maven-shared-utils-3.1.0.jar
       [ERROR] urls[35] = file:/tmp/codon/tmp/cache/.m2/repository/org/ow2/asm/asm/8.0/asm-8.0.jar
       [ERROR] urls[36] = file:/tmp/codon/tmp/cache/.m2/repository/org/ow2/asm/asm-commons/8.0/asm-commons-8.0.jar
       [ERROR] urls[37] = file:/tmp/codon/tmp/cache/.m2/repository/org/ow2/asm/asm-tree/8.0/asm-tree-8.0.jar
       [ERROR] urls[38] = file:/tmp/codon/tmp/cache/.m2/repository/org/ow2/asm/asm-analysis/8.0/asm-analysis-8.0.jar
       [ERROR] urls[39] = file:/tmp/codon/tmp/cache/.m2/repository/org/jdom/jdom2/2.0.6/jdom2-2.0.6.jar
       [ERROR] urls[40] = file:/tmp/codon/tmp/cache/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/shared/maven-dependency-tree/3.0.1/maven-dependency-tree-3.0.1.jar
       [ERROR] urls[41] = file:/tmp/codon/tmp/cache/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/aether/aether-util/0.9.0.M2/aether-util-0.9.0.M2.jar
       [ERROR] urls[42] = file:/tmp/codon/tmp/cache/.m2/repository/commons-io/commons-io/2.6/commons-io-2.6.jar
       [ERROR] urls[43] = file:/tmp/codon/tmp/cache/.m2/repository/org/vafer/jdependency/2.4.0/jdependency-2.4.0.jar
       [ERROR] urls[44] = file:/tmp/codon/tmp/cache/.m2/repository/org/ow2/asm/asm-util/8.0/asm-util-8.0.jar
       [ERROR] urls[45] = file:/tmp/codon/tmp/cache/.m2/repository/com/google/guava/guava/28.2-android/guava-28.2-android.jar
       [ERROR] urls[46] = file:/tmp/codon/tmp/cache/.m2/repository/com/google/guava/failureaccess/1.0.1/failureaccess-1.0.1.jar
       [ERROR] urls[47] = file:/tmp/codon/tmp/cache/.m2/repository/com/google/guava/listenablefuture/9999.0-empty-to-avoid-conflict-with-guava/listenablefuture-9999.0-empty-to-avoid-conflict-with-guava.jar
       [ERROR] urls[48] = file:/tmp/codon/tmp/cache/.m2/repository/org/checkerframework/checker-compat-qual/2.5.5/checker-compat-qual-2.5.5.jar
       [ERROR] urls[49] = file:/tmp/codon/tmp/cache/.m2/repository/com/google/errorprone/error_prone_annotations/2.3.4/error_prone_annotations-2.3.4.jar
       [ERROR] urls[50] = file:/tmp/codon/tmp/cache/.m2/repository/com/google/j2objc/j2objc-annotations/1.3/j2objc-annotations-1.3.jar
       [ERROR] urls[51] = file:/tmp/codon/tmp/cache/.m2/repository/org/apache/commons/commons-lang3/3.7/commons-lang3-3.7.jar
       [ERROR] Number of foreign imports: 1
       [ERROR] import: Entry[import  from realm ClassRealm[maven.api, parent: null]]
       [ERROR] 
       [ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------
       [ERROR] -> [Help 1]
       [ERROR] 
       [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
       [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
       [ERROR] 
       [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
       [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginContainerException
 !     ERROR: Failed to build app with Maven
       We're sorry this build is failing! If you can't find the issue in application code,
       please submit a ticket so we can help: https://help.heroku.com/
 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Java app.
 !     Push failed
```

Below is my pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.5</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.quickaid</groupId>
    <artifactId>quickaid-backend</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>quickaid-backend</name>
    <description>quickaid-backend</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <jvmTarget>1.8</jvmTarget>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.module</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-module-kotlin</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-reflect</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-stdlib-jdk8</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.auth0</groupId>
            <artifactId>java-jwt</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-crypto</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.github.cdimascio</groupId>
            <artifactId>dotenv-kotlin</artifactId>
            <version>6.4.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/kotlin</sourceDirectory>
        <testSourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/test/kotlin</testSourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
                <artifactId>kotlin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <jvmTarget>1.8</jvmTarget>
                    <args>
                        <arg>-Xjsr305=strict</arg>
                    </args>
                    <compilerPlugins>
                        <plugin>spring</plugin>
                    </compilerPlugins>
                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
                        <artifactId>kotlin-maven-allopen</artifactId>
                        <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.7</version>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.shared</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-filtering</artifactId>
                        <version>1.3</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals><goal>copy-dependencies</goal></goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

I don't really understand the problem. Does the application crash because I miss that "RepackageMojo" or does it crash because I don't have the correct Java version installed?

I already tried to update the Java version and also the JVM version but nothing really seemed to help.